# search values within a PySpark paired RDD , for keys coming from another RDD

Tags: pyspark, key-value

I am new to PySpark, I want to do the following,

Consider the following code,

```
import numpy as np
b =np.array([[1,2,100],[3,4,200],[5,6, 300],[7,8, 400]])
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[11,6],[7,8], [1, 2], [7,8]])
RDDa = sc.parallelize(a)
RDDb = sc.parallelize(b)
dsmRDD = RDDb.map(lambda x: (list(x[:2]), x[2]))
```

I want to get the values associated with each value of RDDa as key to dsmRDD,i.e.

```
result = [100, 200, 0, 400, 100, 400]
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not too big you can use the dataframes like this:

```
dfa = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[11,6],[7,8], [1, 2], [7,8]], ["c1", "c2"])
dfb = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,100],[3,4,200],[5,6, 300],[7,8, 400]], ["c1", "c2", "value"])
>>> dfa.join(dfb, on=["c1","c2"], how="left").na.fill(0).show()
+---+---+-----+
| c1| c2|value|
+---+---+-----+
|  7|  8|  400|
|  7|  8|  400|
| 11|  6|    0|
|  3|  4|  200|
|  1|  2|  100|
|  1|  2|  100|
+---+---+-----+

temp = dfa.join(dfb, on=["c1","c2"], how="left").na.fill(0)

>>> [i.value for i in temp.select("value").collect()]
[400, 400, 0, 200, 100, 100]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I will try it now. Just one correction, my data is really big, its just a small example to demonstrate the problem! And I am using PySpark!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggests, you can convert to a dataframe and `join`. In case you are willing to continue with `rdd` only, you can do this,

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[11,6],[7,8], [1, 2], [7,8]])
b = np.array([[1,2,100],[3,4,200],[5,6, 300],[7,8, 400]])

RDDa = sc.parallelize(a)
RDDb = sc.parallelize(b)

dsmRDD = RDDa.zipWithIndex()\
         .map(lambda x: (tuple(x[0].tolist()),(0,x[1])))\
         .leftOuterJoin(RDDb.map(lambda x: (tuple(x[:2].tolist()), x[2])))\
         .map(lambda x: (x[1][0][1], x[1][1]) if x[1][1] is not None else (x[1][0][1],x[1][0][0]))

output = map(lambda x:x[1], sorted(dsmRDD.collect()))
print output
```

which gives you the output,

```py
[100, 200, 0, 400, 100, 400]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But, it is not following the order! The order is important for my work. The proper order should be 100, 200, 0, 400, 100, 400].

Comment: Spark data structures do not preserve the order of rows. What we can do is add an additional index column and sort the rows afterwards. Check the edit.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, do upvote and accept so other users also can find it easily!